# mongodb 3.04 BUG, how to restore the data

Tags: mongodb

I use mongodb to store about 400GB data. And when I tried to ensureIndex, it exit
and I found the backtrace in the log:

```
015-07-03T02:23:09.638+0800 I CONTROL  [conn3]
 0xf7a0f9 0xf19121 0xefe28f 0xefe33c 0x851b4f 0x931422 0xa19793 0xbec614 0x9494ab 0x971dde 0x9f40e4 0x9f506d 0x9f5d7b 0xbbabca 0xad0f00 0x82b88d 0xf2d22b 0x7fe77aa6fb50 0x7fe7795b6e6d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"B7A0F9"},{"b":"400000","o":"B19121"},{"b":"400000","o":"AFE28F"},{"b":"400000","o":"AFE33C"},{"b":"400000","o":"451B4F"},{"b":"400000","o":"531422"},{"b":"400000","o":"619793"},{"b":"400000","o":"7EC614"},{"b":"400000","o":"5494AB"},{"b":"400000","o":"571DDE"},{"b":"400000","o":"5F40E4"},{"b":"400000","o":"5F506D"},{"b":"400000","o":"5F5D7B"},{"b":"400000","o":"7BABCA"},{"b":"400000","o":"6D0F00"},{"b":"400000","o":"42B88D"},{"b":"400000","o":"B2D22B"},{"b":"7FE77AA69000","o":"6B50"},{"b":"7FE7794DB000","o":"DBE6D"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.4", "gitVersion" : "0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.2.0-4-amd64", "version" : "#1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "EB7A0F7D9F202DB3ADD7637D20509D9DE82AC5A1" }, { "b" : "7FFFAECB0000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "804F357CF825E4716BA7DA60414184939D1D3432" }, { "b" : "7FE77AA69000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E2755F1148137BA124B24BF1072EF146FE51F361" }, { "b" : "7FE77A809000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "90B85CC62C41AE65576EA31156205F149B04FD31" }, { "b" : "7FE77A411000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9CC15590792B6F822DBB2ACEF66CB9A89FAA0775" }, { "b" : "7FE77A209000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "514F17B70AF2A2DBC501771B1271138EE35FF3AB" }, { "b" : "7FE77A005000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D0015E317E2EEDCC8F37457A504A1746DE763C49" }, { "b" : "7FE779CFE000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8711429397A5AF8B6269B867D830EDF6E0225B8D" }, { "b" : "7FE779A7C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9233B6861A56025E3379F1FF173C230E66E39B5E" }, { "b" : "7FE779866000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F980B1188708F8D8B5C35D185444AF4CB939AA1E" }, { "b" : "7FE7794DB000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A23A05B5AF000742B37A68C9D8D5A857D01BCB9F" }, { "b" : "7FE77AC85000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A16192716DE58BA171CDA81D39F045BF24849176" }, { "b" : "7FE7792C4000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1EFEB71FD4999C2307570D673A724EA4E1D85267" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x29) [0xf7a0f9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0xE1) [0xf19121]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0xAF) [0xefe28f]
 mongod(+0xAFE33C) [0xefe33c]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo7BSONObj14_assertInvalidEv+0x3DF) [0x851b4f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10RecordData13releaseToBsonEv+0x52) [0x931422]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14CollectionScan4workEPm+0x233) [0xa19793]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor18getNextSnapshottedEPNS_11SnapshottedINS_7BSONObjEEEPNS_8RecordIdE+0xA4) [0xbec614]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15MultiIndexBlock30insertAllDocumentsInCollectionEPSt3setINS_8RecordIdESt4lessIS2_ESaIS2_EE+0x17B) [0x9494ab]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14CmdCreateIndex3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x104E) [0x971dde]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x34) [0x9f40e4]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPS0_iPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0xC1D) [0x9f506d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x28B) [0x9f5d7b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8runQueryEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERKNS_15NamespaceStringERNS_5CurOpES3_+0x77A) [0xbbabca]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0xB10) [0xad0f00]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0xDD) [0x82b88d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x34B) [0xf2d22b]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x6B50) [0x7fe77aa6fb50]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7fe7795b6e6d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

the error_msg is "exception: BSONObj size: 0 (0x0) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: EOO"

How can I restore my data?

Comment: db.repairDatabase() dose not work. And it made the mongod exit.

Comment: that should have resulted in a corrupt index not loss of data entirely

Comment: But when I export the data, I will also get the error. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried dropping the index?

Comment: @BinHe, it's been a while, but have you ever managed to find a solution?